# Get the total number of missed chat on json using php

Tags: php, json, count

just want to know how to get the total numbers of missed chat.
so far here's want i already done:

```
    var json = '{
  "chats": [
    {
      "department_name": "Lesson and Fee Support",
      "id": "1706.2327063.QNoy006lji184",
      "end_timestamp": "2017-06-28T06:16:12Z",
      "referrer_search_terms": "",
      "referrer_search_engine": "",
      "missed": true
    },
    {
      "department_name": "Lesson and Fee Support",
      "id": "1706.2327063.QNoy006lji184",
      "end_timestamp": "2017-06-28T06:16:12Z",
      "referrer_search_terms": "",
      "referrer_search_engine": "",
      "missed": false
    },
    {
      "department_name": "Lesson and Fee Support",
      "id": "1706.2327063.QNoy006lji184",
      "end_timestamp": "2017-06-28T06:16:12Z",
      "referrer_search_terms": "",
      "referrer_search_engine": "",
      "missed": false
    },
    {
      "department_name": "Lesson and Fee Support",
      "id": "1706.2327063.QNoy006lji184",
      "end_timestamp": "2017-06-28T06:16:12Z",
      "referrer_search_terms": "",
      "referrer_search_engine": "",
      "missed": true
    },
    {
      "department_name": "Lesson and Fee Support",
      "id": "1706.2327063.QNoy006lji184",
      "end_timestamp": "2017-06-28T06:16:12Z",
      "referrer_search_terms": "",
      "referrer_search_engine": "",
      "missed": true
    }
  ]
}';

    var obj = JSON.parse(json);

    alert(obj.chats.length);
```

just want to display the total number of missed and not missed chat (true = yes
false = no) and also on php format

thank you,
regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - We're here to help, not to write code for youö Show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts with us and we'll help you. But nobody wants to write code for you.

Comment: Okay, i'll edit my post

Comment: @ivor  .. try this..  `echo count($chats['missed'] == 'false');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can loop through the data and get the count like below:

```
$chats='{
  "chats": [
    {
      "department_name": "Lesson and Fee Support",
      "id": "1706.2327063.QNoy006lji184",
      "end_timestamp": "2017-06-28T06:16:12Z",
      "referrer_search_terms": "",
      "referrer_search_engine": "",
      "missed": true
    },
    {
      "department_name": "Lesson and Fee Support",
      "id": "1706.2327063.QNoy006lji184",
      "end_timestamp": "2017-06-28T06:16:12Z",
      "referrer_search_terms": "",
      "referrer_search_engine": "",
      "missed": false
    },
    {
      "department_name": "Lesson and Fee Support",
      "id": "1706.2327063.QNoy006lji184",
      "end_timestamp": "2017-06-28T06:16:12Z",
      "referrer_search_terms": "",
      "referrer_search_engine": "",
      "missed": false
    },
    {
      "department_name": "Lesson and Fee Support",
      "id": "1706.2327063.QNoy006lji184",
      "end_timestamp": "2017-06-28T06:16:12Z",
      "referrer_search_terms": "",
      "referrer_search_engine": "",
      "missed": true
    },
    {
      "department_name": "Lesson and Fee Support",
      "id": "1706.2327063.QNoy006lji184",
      "end_timestamp": "2017-06-28T06:16:12Z",
      "referrer_search_terms": "",
      "referrer_search_engine": "",
      "missed": true
    }
  ]}';
$chats=json_decode($chats,true);
$chats=$chats['chats'];
if(!empty($chats))
{
    $missed=0;
    $notMissed=0;
    foreach ($chats as $key => $chat) {
        if($chat['missed']){
            $missed++;
        }else{
            $notMissed++;           
        }
    }
    echo '<p><strong>Missed:</strong>'.$missed.'</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Missed:</strong>'.$notMissed.'</p>';
}
```

But i recommend you to get the count from database level so that you can avoid the looping in PHP or JavaScript.

Comment: @ivor if that's the case then you can't. So go for PHP or JavaScript method.

Comment: Yeah... thanks again Man.. by the way... some of my data don't have missed chat... how can i do it on php?...

Comment: You mean to say in some of chat data you don't have missed key or it's value? If so then in PHP loop before you checking the missed key value, make sure you have that key like below:
`//Check the missed key is there in chat data
     if(isset($chat['missed']))
     {
         if($chat['missed']){
             $missed++;
         }else{
             $notMissed++;           
         }
     }`

Comment: like some of the chat don't have missed key... cause some of the chat are via offline msg... there are to type of chat on my json one is type:chat and seconds is type:offline_msg. offline message don't have missed chat

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
len =obj.chats.length;
missedyes=0;
missedno=0;
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
val =obj.chats[i].missed;
if(val==true){missedyes+=1}else{missedno+=1}
}
```

missedyes will be missed chat count  and not mised chat will be missedno count

Answer (score -1):

You can use SQL query to get the count -

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chat WHERE missed = true) as unread_count, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chat WHERE missed = false) as read_count FROM chats LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: This answer isn't correct at all. He wants to retirve data from a JSON file, not from a database. You can't use SQL on JSON, you're mixing up things.

Comment: @Twinfriends Sorry my bad it seems the only option remaining is to loop through the value and get the count.